# How to find the file name of a the document that belongs to an ITextView?

Tags: c#, mef, visual-studio-extensions

I am currently writing a Visual Studio extension and have implemented the function [`TextViewCreated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextviewcreationlistener.textviewcreated) in a class that implements an `ITextViewCreationListener` interface.

The function is called with an `ITextView` parameter that represent the content of the editor window that just has been created. However, I need not just the contend of the edited document but also the path the file it represents, and an `ITextView` object apparently has no method to get that information.

So far, I have used the [`DTE2.ActiveDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.dte2.activedocument?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(EnvDTE80.DTE2.ActiveDocument);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=visualstudiosdk-2022) property, but it does not always work correctly. Especially if one opens a new text window in Visual Studio while another one is already open, `ActiveDocument` refers to the *previous* document.

What can one do to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text;

public string GetDocumentPath(ITextView view)
{
    if (view.TextBuffer.Properties.TryGetProperty(typeof(ITextDocument), out ITextDocument textDocument) && textDocument is not null)
    {
       return textDocument.FilePath;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where did you find that information?

Comment: @m-q Bits and pieces from everywhere.