# Where is ITextBuffer.Properties documented?

Tags: c#, mef, visual-studio-extensions

As answer to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695060/how-to-find-the-file-name-of-a-the-document-that-belongs-to-an-itextview), I was told to use a specific entry from an `ITextBuffer.Properties` object. Which was a good idea and the right thing to do in this case, but it leads to a new question: Where can one find such information?

More concrete: Is there a description of the entries of `ITextBuffer.Properties` somewhere in the web that one can use? I have googled (with DuckDuckGo) and did not find anything.

Comment: When I type `"ITextBuffer"` into goole, I get a link to [ITextBuffer Interface (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.itextbuffer?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) where I can click on the [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.utilities.ipropertyowner.properties?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#microsoft-visualstudio-utilities-ipropertyowner-properties) link. In VS you can type F1 to get info about the element under the text cursor.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes, of course. But it does not tell me which properties the `Properties` attribute in an `ITextBuffer` object has, only how to handle a generic `IPropertyOwner`object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "property bag" pattern, i.e. a place for random features to dump random stuff in they might need. It's also needed because there's a lot of times you need to create some extra data object or something processing a ITextBuffer that needs to have the same lifetime as the buffer, so you can stick it in the property bag. Reaching in and grabbing some properties from it is very close to relying on implementation details and is not a generally recommended pattern.

(That said, the previous question's suggestion for ITextDocument is often the way it's done for that specific case...)